# Why are my routes being removed/replaced when connected to vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

Since I work on customers sites and most of the time I need to be connected to my company's network (vpn), I usually create routes to access customers servers. However, sometimes when I'm connected to my company's vpn, the routes are removed right before I add them.

If I do a `route add` and right after a `ping` the server replies for one or two requests and then I start to get time out. If I try to remove a route (let's say `route delete 0.0.0.0`) it'll be added right after too.

Is there something I can do to avoid that? Since it does not happen every time, but when it does I have to reboot, reconnect to vpn and create the routes.
Also, persistent routes stays in the table but does not seem to have any effect.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What client software you use connect, and what your settings for it are, are very relevant.

Comment: @Doc Juniper Networks. I did not see anything relevant in the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the VPN software is enforcing a security policy that prohibits connections to others while being connected to the VPN.
(To prevent your computer acting as a pass-though for anything malicious from the local/customer network trying to infiltrate your company LAN via the VPN.)
This is a fairly normal situation.  Most companies that issue VPN access to their off-site users do this nowadays.

You may be able to get an exception. Or the company policy may demand this is a mandatory thing. Either way you need to contact your sys-admin to find out what is going on.

Comment: Makes sense. However, it does work sometimes. It seems that when I add the routes right after connecting to the vpn, it works during all day. But if I try to add the routes after some time (can't tell if minutes or hours) it does not work.

Comment: Is your company computer joined to the domain you are VPNíng into ? If that is the case the domain-computer policies are usually used to enforce this. Typically a Windows system will poll these policies once every hour. So you connect to the VPN at first you add routes without issue. Policy gets polled. After that adding routes is blocked. It could have been worse. The sys-admin could have set it up so you couldn't add your own routes at all even when NOT on the VPN.